# jQuery Cycle Plugin - hover on pause image?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to display a trasparent .png using the pause command in the jQuery cycle plugin?

I can get it to pause on hover over my DIV, but would like to throw a paused icon in teh center of the div on hover...

any thoughts?

Comment: Which part are you actually having trouble with? Showing a "paused" icon?

Comment: yes, i can get it to pause on hover, but am unable to figure out how to display an image once this action is envoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure jQuery.cycle doesn't have this built in. However, you can always tie something to the same element as caused the pause:

```
$('#gallery').cycle({pause:1});
$('#gallery').hover(function() {
  $('#pauseIcon').show();
}, function() {
  $('#pauseIcon').hide();
});
```

and/or

```
$('#pause').click(function() {
  $('#gallery').cycle('pause');
  $('#pauseIcon').toggle();
}
```

Comment: Sweet...your first option seemed easiest and works great.  I made a 100x100 div with a transparent background image... one quirk... when i mouse over the 100x100 div ...it flickers...any resolution or thoughts as to why?

Comment: That's probably because when you're hovering over the 100x100div, you're no longer hovering over the gallery. So it gets hidden, and since you're now hovering over #gallery again, gets shown, then hidden, etc. You could make the hover function $('#gallery').append('<div id="pauseIcon"></div>'); with the appropriate $('#pauseIcon').remove(); afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Think of them as separate.  For example, have cycle pause on hover, meanwhile, you have a div wrapping your viewable image frame which contains a pause image positioned appropriately that's shown when you hover in the div.

Answer (score 0):

The Slides of a slideshow plugin for jQuery has one option 'hoverPause', you could check source code from http://slidesjs.com